# Is there a way to get the time of the TimePicker without using the TimePickerDialog?

Tags: java, android, time, timepicker

I want to know if there is a way to get the time that the user has set in a TimePicker on the screen without using a Dialog. I don't see the point in creating a button that will pop up a TimePickerDialog when I can just have the TimePicker on the screen. I.e. There is no point in having two TimePickers as can be seen in this tutorial and many other similar TimePicker tutorials: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/

I am using picker.getCurrentHour() and picker.getCurrentMinute() but it just returns me the system's current time after I press a button. Is there no way to get the time that the user has entered?

This is how I retrieve the time after clicking a button:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_time);
    picker = new TimePicker(SetTimeActivity.this);
    Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.saveAlarmButton); 
    save.setOnClickListener(onSave);                
}

private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        hour=picker.getCurrentHour();
        min=picker.getCurrentMinute();

        System.out.println(hour + " : " + min);         
    }
};


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SetTimeActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveAlarmButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Save" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Set time for alarm"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But it just gives me the current time.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's not working, I'd take a look at the TimePickerDialog source to see if that works differently, but just from glancing at it it looks like it's working the exact same way.

Comment: You are creating picker that isn't added to layout. That's why you get current time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The picker is there...I am seeing and and touching it. Literally.

Comment: Add layout xml, so I can help you. You need to use `findViewById`

Comment: Ah, I see. I added the xml above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work properly. Probably the issue appear when you are trying to input date through number input. It is due to `NumberPicker` update, it is done ones picker lose focus. So you can try to make sure that picker lose its focus, so it will consume current user input:

```
picker.clearFocus();
hour=picker.getCurrentHour();
min=picker.getCurrentMinute();
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the [picker classes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) is that it opens a dialog to pick something:

> Android provides controls for the user to pick a time or pick a date
>   as ready-to-use dialogs.

Of course, you can always try out other solutions that provide you custom pickers and get their layout, for example [this one](http://code.google.com/p/datetimepicker/) , [here](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-timepicker) , [here](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker) and [here](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker).

This way, you can put the layout of the picker wherever you wish, without any dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the widget to an activity just like any other. You can get the date/time like so:

```
    // Format date and time from pickers
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Comment: As alluded to in the question, my problem is that it returns the system time not the picked time.